# Renci.SshNet not working in SSIS script task when run as SQL job

Tags: ssis, sftp

I am have having a very strange issue here. I have built a task which downloads all the files that have been uploaded that day to a SFTP server. When I run the package manually, by executing it in BIDS, everything works as expected. When I use a SQL job to run it completes saying that it was successful but no files are downloaded.

I have even built a separate application which does the downloading and using an "Execute Process" task, which again runs correctly when run outside of the SQL Job.

I have check the write permissions on the destination folder and opened it up for every account being able to read/write, but this made no difference. I have also added an SSIS extension that has a SFTP task that I am currently fighting with to get working. I'd rather understand why the current process doesn't work.

I am using Renci.SshNet for the SFTP operations and the code I use is below. Why would the job report a success, but not actually download anything?

```
using (var sftp = new SftpClient("host", "username", "password"))
{
    sftp.Connect();
    var files = sftp.ListDirectory("/incoming");
    foreach (SftpFile file in files)
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

        using (var stream = File.Create(DestinationFolder + file.Name))
        {
            sftp.DownloadFile(file.FullName, stream);
        }
    }
    sftp.Disconnect();
}
```